# Timeline from 2 related tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Let's say I have a `screenshots` table and a `replies` table. So: every screenshot can have multiple replies (one-to-many). Now, I want to create a combined timeline of the two, but in reality, they're pretty unrelated (in structure).

How can I select data from both tables, ordering by their publish time, descending; when for example, I can have a post, a few comments, then another post; because that would be how the timeline happened?

Normally selecting from both combines the tables; but I don't want that to happen. On that subject, I also need the tables to be distinguishable. Here's the structure for the tables...

```
--
-- Table structure for table `screenshots`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screenshots` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ext` varchar(4) NOT NULL default 'png',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `screenshot_replies`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screenshot_replies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;
```

**Note:** I realize this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197449/joining-multiple-unrelated-tables-in-mysql) but I didn't find the solution there working for me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) in this case:

```
(SELECT id, time, 'screenshots' as tableName FROM screenshots)
UNION
(SELECT id, time, 'replies' as tableName FROM screenshot_replies)
ORDER BY time ASC
```

<strike>You can get the tablename of a field by using the [mysql_tablename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php) function in php</strike>
You can indicate the tablename as a column in the result set

Comment: I'll play with this and see how it fits -- so far it's working with a few drawbacks in the way the rows are organized -- thanks! I'll mark this as the answer if everything turns out good :)

Comment: Just looked up mysql_tablename, appears to be deprecated? Also, I'm caching my results in an array, I don't think it would still work

Comment: Use "union all" instead of just "union" to avoid an implicit extra "distinct" step

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I come across a  problem like this, where you're finding it impossible to do something because you can't built a query which will extract the data, I have to start wondering do you have the right data model?

Start with what data you want to extract, and then build a model which allows that, not the reverse, and you'll find it much easiler in the long term, and also probably faster performance and quite often better flexibility.

Looking at those tables, I'd have to ask why have two of them? What's wrong with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screenshots` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ext` varchar(4) default 'png',
  `parent` int(11),
  `text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

That would allow you to do what you want, easily telling if it's a screen shot (if ext is set), a reply (if parent is set) or ... since the model now allows it ... a screenshot which is a reply!!!

Comment: That structure isn't required by my needs, haha :P I don't need a screenshot which is a reply, and it's a lot easier for me to organize them separately.

Comment: Oh, and my structure was awesome before I decided to make a joined timeline for an RSS feed. The website itself is functional and working almost flawlessly, this is just a boost I want to give it.